# Java Records to be used as JSF values

Tags: jsf, el, java-record

I am working on a simple JSF web application(mostly for learning) using Java 15 and JSF 2.3 plus PrimeFaces 8 and I am using a simple java record for modelling an entity. The application does not use any database.

My question is if it is possible to use the java records as values in the xhtml pages like this

```
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.randomId}" />
    </p:column>
```

becasue I am receiving the following error
`javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'com.company.Car' does not have the property 'id'.`.
I tried putting `car.year()`, but it did not work.
The definition of the record is this

```
public record Car (String randomId, String randomBrand, int randomYear, String randomColor, int randomPrice, boolean randomSoldState) {
}
```

In the pom.xml, I am using the following api

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Would you please share car class, to help you better?

Comment: actually the car class, is that record form the question, but here it is
`public record Car (String randomId, String randomBrand, int randomYear, String randomColor, int randomPrice, boolean randomSoldState) {
}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically speaking, the issue is not in JSF, but in EL. The package name of the exception already hints this: `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException`. The EL version being used doesn't recognize Java Records yet. Jakarta EE 8 ties with Java 8, but the Java Records feature was introduced in Java 14. Theoretically, it would at earliest only be natively supported in an EL version associated with a Jakarta EE version associated with Java 14. But even that is very unlikely because Java Records is only available as a "preview feature" (and thus not by default enabled at all).

Coming back to your concrete problem, using the method expression syntax as in `#{car.randomId()}` did actually work for me on WildFly 21. In any case, EL resolving can be always customized with a custom `ELResolver`. Here's a kickoff example which checks for records based on `Class#isRecord()` and collects fields available via `Class#getRecordComponents()` as properties:

```
public class RecordELResolver extends ELResolver {

    private static final Map<Class<?>, Map<String, PropertyDescriptor>> RECORD_PROPERTY_DESCRIPTOR_CACHE = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private static boolean isRecord(Object base) {
        return base != null && base.getClass().isRecord();
    }
    
    private static Map<String, PropertyDescriptor> getRecordPropertyDescriptors(Object base) {
        return RECORD_PROPERTY_DESCRIPTOR_CACHE
            .computeIfAbsent(base.getClass(), clazz -> Arrays
                .stream(clazz.getRecordComponents())
                .collect(Collectors
                    .toMap(RecordComponent::getName, recordComponent -> {
                        try {
                            return new PropertyDescriptor(recordComponent.getName(), recordComponent.getAccessor(), null);
                        }
                        catch (IntrospectionException e) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                        }
                    })));
    }
    
    private static PropertyDescriptor getRecordPropertyDescriptor(Object base, Object property) {
        PropertyDescriptor descriptor = getRecordPropertyDescriptors(base).get(property);
        
        if (descriptor == null) {
            throw new PropertyNotFoundException("The record '" + base.getClass().getName() + "' does not have the field '" + property + "'.");
        }

        return descriptor;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
        if (!isRecord(base) || property == null) {
            return null;
        }

        PropertyDescriptor descriptor = getRecordPropertyDescriptor(base, property);

        try {
            Object value = descriptor.getReadMethod().invoke(base);
            context.setPropertyResolved(base, property);
            return value;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ELException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getType(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
        if (!isRecord(base) || property == null) {
            return null;
        }

        PropertyDescriptor descriptor = getRecordPropertyDescriptor(base, property);
        context.setPropertyResolved(true);
        return descriptor.getPropertyType();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getCommonPropertyType(ELContext context, Object base) {
        if (!isRecord(base)) {
            return null;
        }

        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadOnly(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
        if (!isRecord(base)) {
            return false;
        }

        getRecordPropertyDescriptor(base, property); // Forces PropertyNotFoundException if necessary.
        context.setPropertyResolved(true);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property, Object value) {
        if (!isRecord(base)) {
            return;
        }

        throw new PropertyNotWritableException("Java Records are immutable");
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<FeatureDescriptor> getFeatureDescriptors(ELContext context, Object base) {
        if (!isRecord(base)) {
            return null;
        }

        Map rawDescriptors = getRecordPropertyDescriptors(base);
        return rawDescriptors.values().iterator();
    }

}
```

In order to get it to work, register it in `faces-config.xml` as below:

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>com.example.RecordELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

The real work is done in `getValue()` method. It basically locates the `java.lang.reflect.Method` representing the accessor of the Java Record and invokes it.

That said, a Java Record is insuitable to substitute a fullworthy JavaBean, primarily because Java Records are **immutable**. So they cannot be used as real (JPA) entities because these are supposed to be mutable. Java Records are at most useful as read-only DTOs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanations and code sample!

Comment: Small Nitpick: `return String.class` for `getCommonPropertyType` - as you address record components with a String.

Comment: And for `getFeatureDescriptors`: `return return RECORD_COMPONENT_CACHE
            .computeIfAbsent(...).values().map(p -> new java.beans.PropertyDescriptor(p.getName(), p.getAccessor(), null).iterator();` may work.

Comment: @Johannes: Absolutely correct. It was just a kickoff example based off the existing `javax.el.BeanELResolver`. The mentioned methods are actually never invoked during a normal JSF lifecycle, but I'll update the code.

Comment: Much appreciation for the additional comments.

Answer (score 1):

With Spring mvc running on tomcat 9 using :

```
${car.randomId()}
```

works

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper in the stack trace and examine the code for reading the properties, it seems that for the moment, the reading the properties form the java records is not yes implemented.

Maybe in a future version.

Note that I will update the answer as soon as I will find relevant information about this subject.

Update 8.11.2020
Unfortunately, I have misinterpreted the scope of the records.

In a real world application, my entity would be a JPA entity.